# How to check for database changes to a mongoose document object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Imagine processing an order as follows:

```
Order.find({_id: '5faae1245e387720f4a4ef3a'})
    .then(async order => {
        const products = order.products; //array of products
        for(let index = 0; index < products.length; index++){
            const if_success = await processProduct(products[index]);
            //Do something based on if_success
            /* ... */
        }
    })
    .catch()
```

There could be a large array of products attached to the order and the `for` loop has to process them all sequentially, which may take a while. The trick is that while the `for` loop is running blissfully unaware of its surroundings, a user can make a change to order `5faae1245e387720f4a4ef3a` via their web portal, in which case I want to break the loop.

I could certainly accomplish that by running a query with each iteration of the loop to check if the order has pending changes, but I'm loath to do that because I don't want to hammer the database with those queries as there may a number of these loops running in parallel for different orders.

Another, not hugely dissimilar, solution is to query the DB for pending changes every x iterations of the loop; something of the `if(index % x === 0)` variety.

The latter is what I'm leaning towards at this point, but maybe I'm missing something.

I feel like mongoose can help me here so conceptually I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
Order.find({_id: '5faae1245e387720f4a4ef3a'})
    .then(async order => {
        const products = order.products; //array of products
        for(let index = 0; index < products.length; index++){
            const if_success = await processProduct(products[index]);
            //Do something based on if_success
            /* ... */
            if(order.metadata.ifDocChanged)
                break;
        }
    })
    .catch()
```

Is there a way to do something similar with mongoose?

Comment: any change you can be more succinct, please

Comment: If you can elucidate what I'm asking more succinctly, I'm all ears.

Comment: I'd like to help but my eyes can't go through blocks of words :-( Maybe later will try again :-)